# Oracle Stored Procs with SSRS 2012

Tags: reporting-services, oracle11g, ssrs-2012

I've been trying to figure this out for the last day or so and after numerous attempts, I'm still struggling to find a solution.   Essentially I have an Oracle Datasource setup in SSRS, where using the current "providers" available for Oracle are the following under OLE DB:

[image: SSRS Connection Properties]

Or flat out using the "Oracle" connection type:

[image]

The issue I'm facing is when attempting to call an Oracle Stored Procedure.   The only provider that seems to work is "Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Oracle" (Provider=MSDAORA;Data Source=DBNAME),  where when selecting that Datasource, I can select my PROC from the drop-down (see below) and hit "refresh fields", and everything works, no problem.  I don't even have to specify any parameters as it recognized them automatically and adds them.  The problem is that the MSDORA is being deprecated (from what I've read), and several attempts to install ODAC (32 and 64 bit) on the server have proven unsuccessful seeing as the reporting service on the server doesn't seem to recognize the provider (tested using a UDL file).

[image]

So, figured I'd resort to using the "Oracle" provider / connection method, but despite my attempts with or without passing the parameters, I keep getting errors.  Either this if I don't pass any parameters:

```
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'SSRSTEST'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

Or this error if I do add the parameter value at the end:

```
ORA-00911: invalid character
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_UTILITY", line 156
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

[image]

It's safe to assume that the data source provider is in part the source of my problem, but surely there must be a way to call an Oracle Proc via SSRS using something other than MSDORA, or at least I hope there is.  I've tried installing both 32 and 64 bit versions of the Oracle client (11 and 12c), registering the dlls manually (regsvr32) but I still can't seem to resolve this.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.